# column resize issue in gridpanel

Tags: extjs

I have a defect assigned to me which states that columns are difficult to resize on a grid. this appears to be true, the mouseover which triggers the col-resize cursor display is quite tiny. Is there a way to increase the "hot area" between colums in order to make the colum resize function more user friendly ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. To do that, you have to use an undocumented config option for the GridView:

Within the configuration for your grid:

```
viewConfig: {
   splitHandleWidth: 10  // default is 5
}
```

But this doesn't increase it optically, it's just that a larger part of the headers is used as handles for resizing.